# React Native app not building in release version

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm currently working on a React-Native Project, which did work out pretty well but as I tried to release it i noticed the app is crashing after a second. The strange thing is that it worked well in debug mode, and still is. Only the release version is crashing.

Where can I start to look? Did anybody experience something similar?

Comment: this is very well documented on react-native's documentation.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago i have been succesfully to make release version my react native project. First you need to generate keystore and then change variable in your app/build.grade.

You can follow [App Signing Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) reference to fix it 
 or you can also follow from react native documentation [Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

I hope that references can help your problem.